# PDO preparing and binding MySQL functions

Tags: php, function, pdo, escaping

We have dynamic queries, and some of them say "If `$x is null` use `NOW()` otherwise use the date passed in" I would like to know what is the best way to escape that?

So for example, is this the correct way to bind?

```
public function doSomething($date = null){
    // My wrapper for PDO
    // params: Query, Replacements
    $db->query("select * from my_table where date >= ?", array(
        ($date === null ? "now()" : $date)
    ));
}
```

This is how `query` does the binding (if that is important):

```
protected function _bind($query, $params){
    if(strpos($query, "?")){
        array_unshift($params, null);
        unset($params[0]);
    }
    foreach($params as $key => $val){
        $type = $this->_getPDOType($val);
        $this->stmt->bindValue($key, $val, $type);
    }
}
```

So, what is the best way to bind values like this? Am I doing it correctly?

Comment: Bit confusing, you are using unnamed parameters in your query, and then using "bindValue" to bind named parameters?

Comment: @amrhady I updated it to show the actual bind feature

Comment: Do you mind please explaining what the if statement block(with strpos) is doing?

Comment: Since PDO uses an offset of `1` instead of `0` (when using `?`) unlike an array we need to make the first key `1` instead of `0`, and that is what that is doing.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it seems correct but I would also check if the $date - variable if it's an actual date first (before putting it into the array).

```
if (DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date) !== FALSE) {
    $db->query("select * from my_table where date >= ?", array(
        ($date === null ? "now()" : $date)
    ));
}
```

**Edit**

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date);
$db->query("select * from my_table where date >= ?", array(
    (!$date ? "now()" : $date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"))
));
```

Comment: Yeah I do check, that was just an example for simplicity.

Comment: Ok, then I don't see any problems with it

Comment: **Off Topic:** your if is wrong, it also needs to check for null

Comment: @TheBoogieMan - that condiition is checked with $date === null ? "now()" : $date).

Comment: But it will never get there with the if statement, as passing `null` to the function will return false, so it will skip over the query.

Comment: You shouldn't really have to put any conditions in the array, it should be fine just doing: array($date) .

Comment: I edited your answer, and I believe that is how it should look

Comment: I just realized this won't work. I it will try an insert now as a string: `where date >= 'now()'`